# PostGIS - Database installation of functions failed

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.2

I'm using Windows 7 Home SP1 64bit and trying to install PostGIS 2.0.3 for PostgreSQL x64 9.2. PostgreSQL installation worked fine and I've connected to/modified databases. The same error listed below occur when I try to install the 32bit PostGIS through the application stack builder.

I've tried installing PostGIS through application stack builder 3.1.0 and the windows installer from this [link](http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg92/). In both cases I get the same error message:

```
"Database installation of PostGIS functions failed"
```

the error log states:

```
"ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/postgis-2.0.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.".
```

When I go to the directory "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/", I see the file "postgis-2.0.dll" present.

Any ideas for how to proceed? Based on the ticket located [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1824/), it looks like it has something to do with the "libxml2.dll" and "libxml2-2.dll" files, but I don't follow the resolution. Should I be copying something from one folder to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In <%INSTALL_DIR%>\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin, copy libxml2.dll over libxml2-2.dll. Seemed to work for me.

Comment: Also works for 9.5. Can't believe this is still the way to fix postgis in Windows.... :)

Comment: Guys, I have the same trouble.. but in my C:\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin I have both - libxml2.dll and libxml2-2.dll ... what should I do?

Comment: @Dennis I'm having the same issue.  Did you find a solution?  When I tried to replace `libxml2-2.dll` with `libxml2.dll`, postgreSQL would shut down when I try to run it.